# Wordpress Gutenberg Blog in Block Pattern

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

Even though Gutenberg hag a 'widget' to add Blog Posts to your page, I need custom HTML wrapping this widget. Can anyone point me to a way to add a Custom block-pattern or how to create / modify the Blog post widget?

It's important that adding the blog post section / widget to a Page is user friendly, so preferrably no shortcodes etc...

PS, as you may have noticed, I have only been developing for block-patterns and blocks for a couple of days

Thanks!

Comment: Small update - I can easily change:

`wp-includes/blocks/latest-posts.php` around line `183` but that would prevent me from updating WP, so maybe I could override / extend this?

Comment: Second update; 
I can convert the blog-widget into a 'group' in the admin, then add a custom-class and edit everything from there.

Still would love a cleaner solution?